Gesture event is not triggered on real device if view is outside of parent view bounds
I am facing an issue that occurs only on real device, specifically, I am trying to trigger gesture recognizer and expand the image with animation by tapping on image profile view which is inside of a custom UIView that is assigned to navigationItem.titleView.
The image profile view is outside of the parent view frame, so I am aware that point(inside:with:) function needs to be implemented and return true in order for gesture to be recognized, however it is still not recognize, so I tried to call the gesture selector function from inside point(inside:with:).
This works as expected on simulator however, doesn't work on real device (point(inside:with:) is not trigger on the device).
This is the output on the simulator:

I also tried to use hitTest(_:with:) without any luck.
Any suggestions on how to debug this kind of issue would be appreciated.
Code for testing:
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

let button = UIButton()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupButton()
}

func setupButton() {
    view.addSubview(button)
    view.backgroundColor = .brown
    button.setTitle("next", for: .normal)
    button.backgroundColor = .green
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(pushToNavVC), for: .touchUpInside)
    
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
        button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
        button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
        button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50),
    ])
}

@objc func pushToNavVC() {
    let secondVc = SecondViewController()
    navigationController?.pushViewController(secondVc, animated: true)
 }
}

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .brown
    setupNavigationBar()
 }

private func setupNavigationBar() {
    let titleView = CustomTitleView(name: "John Doe", lastSeen: "Last seen 5 min ago")
    navigationItem.titleView = titleView
 }
}


class CustomTitleView: UIView {
  let nameLabel: UILabel
  let lastSeenLabel: UILabel
  let profileImage: UIImageView!

  private var temporaryDimmView: UIView!
  private var temporaryImageView: UIView!
  
 init(name: String, lastSeen: String) {
    nameLabel = UILabel()
    lastSeenLabel = UILabel()
    profileImage = UIImageView()
    
    super.init(frame: .zero)
    
    setupViews(name: name, lastSeen: lastSeen)
 }

 required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
     fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
 }

 private func setupViews(name: String, lastSeen: String) {
    nameLabel.text = name
    nameLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 16)
    
    lastSeenLabel.text = lastSeen
    lastSeenLabel.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)
    lastSeenLabel.textColor = .gray
    
    profileImage.image = UIImage(named: "your_image_name_here")
    profileImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    profileImage.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
    
    let imageTapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(animateProfileImage))
    profileImage.addGestureRecognizer(imageTapGesture)
    
    let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [nameLabel, lastSeenLabel])
    stackView.axis = .vertical
    stackView.alignment = .center
    
    addSubview(stackView)
    addSubview(profileImage)
    
    stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
        stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
        stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 40),
        stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -40),
        
        profileImage.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: 50),
        profileImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30),
        profileImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30),
        profileImage.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerYAnchor),
        widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200)
    ])
}

@objc func animateProfileImage() {
    guard let window = window else { return }
    temporaryDimmView = setupTemporaryDimmView(withFrame: window.frame)
    temporaryImageView = setupTemporaryImageView()
    
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations: {
        self.profileImage.isHidden = true
        self.temporaryImageView.center = window.center
        self.temporaryImageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 8, y: 8)
        self.temporaryDimmView.alpha = 0.85
    })
}

@objc func dismissProfileImage(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

    let imageFrame = profileImage.convert(profileImage.bounds, to: window)
    
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        self.temporaryDimmView.alpha = 0
        self.temporaryImageView.transform.a = 1
        self.temporaryImageView.transform.d = 1
        self.temporaryImageView.frame.origin = imageFrame.origin
    } completion: { _ in
        self.temporaryDimmView.removeFromSuperview()
        self.temporaryImageView.removeFromSuperview()
        self.temporaryDimmView = nil
        self.temporaryImageView = nil
        self.profileImage.isHidden = false
    }
}

/// As of my knowledge, this function should trigger gesture recognizer
/// that is attached to views which are outside of their parent/superview frame.
/// However, it does not in this case, so i call animateProfileImage() inside it
override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool
{
    if super.point(inside: point, with: event) {return true}
    
    for subview in subviews {
        let subviewPoint = subview.convert(point, from: self)
        if subview.point(inside: subviewPoint, with: event) {
            animateProfileImage()
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
 }
}

// temp functions that are created when image animation starts
extension CustomTitleView {
  private func setupTemporaryImageView() -> UIView {
     let imageFrame = profileImage.convert(profileImage.bounds, to: window)
     let animatedImageView = UIImageView(frame: imageFrame)
     animatedImageView.image = profileImage.image
     animatedImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
     window?.addSubview(animatedImageView)
    
     return animatedImageView
 }

 private func setupTemporaryDimmView(withFrame frame: CGRect) -> UIView {
     let dimmView = UIView(frame: frame)
     dimmView.backgroundColor = .black
     dimmView.alpha = 0
     window?.addSubview(dimmView)
    
     let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissProfileImage))
    dimmView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    
    return dimmView
 }
}


The way to make a view outside of its superview touchable is to override hitTest(_:with:). I don't see you doing that. Please note that it would better just to avoid the whole issue and not have a view outside of its superview in the first place. (By the way, the title is wrong, so maybe your thinking is wrong; the question is not the relationship of a subview to its superview's frame, it's the relationship of a subview's frame to its superview's bounds.)

The thing is, that hitTest(_:with:) is not triggered also on real device

Because you're implementing it on the wrong view?

I had implemented it on CustomTitleView, the view that is then set to navigationItem.titleView, why is it wrong? What view should I then be implementing it on?

The thing is, that I wouldn't do this at all in the way you're doing it. As I said before, I wouldn't have a view outside of its superview in the first place.
